# kubeadm init command failing on ubuntu master node

Tags: kubernetes

**kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.56.103 --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16**

getting following error

```
W0501 02:23:32.828806    8629 configset.go:202] WARNING: kubeadm cannot validate component configs for API groups [kubelet.config.k8s.io kubeproxy.config.k8s.io]
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.18.2
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
    [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR Port-10259]: Port 10259 is in use
    [ERROR Port-10257]: Port 10257 is in use
    [ERROR Port-10250]: Port 10250 is in use
    [ERROR Port-2380]: Port 2380 is in use
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[ERROR Port-10259]: Port 10259 is in use
[ERROR Port-10257]: Port 10257 is in use
[ERROR Port-10250]: Port 10250 is in use
[ERROR Port-2380]: Port 2380 is in use
```

Above error shows ports are in use.

In kubernetes

- 10259 => default port for kube-scheduler
- 10257 => default port for kube-controller-manager
- 10250 => default port for kubelet
- 2380 => etcd use this

It seems `kubeadm init` was already called on this node. Run `kubeadm reset` before running `kubeadm init` command.

If that does not work for you then you can check which process using those port by running

```
netstat -lnp | grep 1025
```

and you can kill those port by running

```
sudo fuser -k <port>/tcp
```

Comment: I am running `kubeadm init` at a brand new ubuntu 18.04 cloud instance, every port is available, but still get an error with warning like this: `W0603 01:50:38.774021   16094 configset.go:202] WARNING: kubeadm cannot validate component configs for API groups [kubelet.config.k8s.io kubeproxy.config.k8s.io]`

Comment: Have you tried `kubeadm reset --cri-socket <your socket here if not default>`?